# Размещения изображения и текста отдельно от остальной разметки

Tags: html, css

Как разместить изображение и описание отдельно от другой части статьи. Потому что описание сливается с остальным текстом. Когда два изображения, то идет изображение, потом описание, потом изображение и описание, но все сливается.

Comment: Вообще, приведите пример (рисунок, как надо), а то не очень ясно.

Comment: Я только начинаю изучать данный язык. Сложновато объяснить. Просто в html идет поочередно и получается, что среди текстов ставлю изображение. Текст обтекает изображение, но хочу, чтобы описание было рядом с текстом, а потом под изображением как бы абзац начинался уже остальной текст. Получается, идет текст, потом изображение с его обтекающим описанием и потом с абзаца под изображением идет остальной текст. Вот как-то так. Прошу прощение сразу за "подробное" описание проблемки.

Answer (score 1):

Поместите изображение и описание в один абзац, а последующий текст в другой.
Пример          `<p> ...изображение, описание...</p>` `<p>...текст...</p>`